# HTTPS downloads/uploads

Tags: security, ssl, https, upload, download

my website is accessible through https, so it provides a secure connection to the user that has to fill in some sensible details.

Does the security extend also to downloads and uploads done through the website? 
For example. I provide a simple "Browse" button to upload a file, or a link to download a file hosted on the website, is the download/upload secure as well?

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "secure" ?

Answer (score 1):

**Let me explain some things first.**

SSL is just a layer or a connection., whichever data that is being sent/received to your website are in packets and are successfully encrypted, whilst this hopefully prevents "Man-in-the-Middle Attack".[Good news..right ? :-)]

But .. as per your request **No SSL does not ensure security when it regards to uploads/downloads.**

You need to **add exception to file types [MIME]** that you are letting other (end-users) to upload to your server [Here, SSL has no work here]. **You have to set these limitations on your coding part**., If these things are not handled properly, a hacker may upload a SHELL script on your upload section and can gain root access to your server and you can't blame this on SSL.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable info.
And specifically about downloads, what if the user downloads a file from my website? Is that download secure?

Comment: Again it depends on the code what you have written.. say if your code is something like.. `http://www.yourwebsite.com/download.php?=ironman3.mp3`. In this case, if your code ain't secure.. a hacker can traverse files like `download.php?=../../../php.ini` . Hence it depends on your code again., not the SSL.

Comment: Thanks again, I'll do my best to avoid those mistakes. But, from the user's perspective, is the download of that iroman3.mp3 more secure than a normal http? In other words, will the packets of the file arrive encrypted to the final user? I guess the answer is yes, but just want to be secure. 
Another question is how it is possible to make the download of a file from a website even more secure, preserving simplicity (click on a link is very easy, but other solutions probably not)